# Android and Google contact sync: "Starred in Android"

Tags: contacts

How can I sync Android contacts directly with Google?

The problem is I have several groups under my Google account ("contacts", "contacts2", "Starred in Android"). When I try to add a new contact from my Android device, under the groups tab I can see only "contacts" and "contacts2" named groups, but not "Starred in Android". And when I choose to sync contacts with Google, it syncs with contacts which are under the "Starred in Android" named group. So as you can guess every time when I add a new contact from my phone, I must change this contact's group to "Starred in Android" from Gmail.

Answer (score 2):

"Starred in Android" is a special group. You don't add a person to the group through the groups interface, but by tapping the little star on the contact profile on your phone. That sorts them to the top of the "favorites" list.

There's no concept of a starred contact on the web app side, so I guess they decided to create this special group. (In fact, from what I recall, this group won't be created until you actually "star" a contact.)

So, don't scroll to the bottom of your contact to try to add them to the "Starred in Android" group. Scroll to the top and tap the star.

Comment: There are "phone" and "contacts" apps. I want to reach my contacts from default "phone" app not "contacts" app. I can see all groups from contacts app but  not from default phone app.

Comment: What you're asking for isn't possible from the Phone app.

Comment: So how can i add my contacts directly to "Starred in Android" group. I dont want to go to contacts app, search for contact which i just added and use star icon every time. By the way there are thousands of numbers at my contact list.There are many same numbers coming from Whatsapp etc.

Comment: Add them in the Contacts app in the first place. I almost never use the Phone app directly. I find who I want to call in the People app and select the number I want to dial from there. Of course, the whole point of the star is to quickly find those **few** contacts that you want to force to the top of the list. If you have "thousands" of starred contacts you're using the feature in a way it was not intended.